# How can I create random graph generator using Spark-Scala without GraphX library?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph

I am new to Spark-Scala. I want to create a random graph generator using RMat Algorithm using Spark-Scala. I am aware that GraphX provides a utility GraphGenerator file. I need to implement RMat without GraphX.